# Cannot archive iOS project in Xcode 10 beta 4

Tags: xcode, react-native, cocoapods, xcode10

I've been trying to archive my using Xcode 10 beta 4, and after getting past [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/20774) I got a different issue when archiving the project:

```
/Users/rodrigovasconcelos/MyApp/mobile/ios/MyApp-Bridging-Header.h:5:9: error: 'React/RCTBridgeModule.h' file not found
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
        ^
1 error generated.
<unknown>:0: error: failed to emit precompiled header '/Users/rodrigovasconcelos/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-cpkesijquffkhgfgaagxybgvqlpr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Edge/PrecompiledHeaders/MyApp-Bridging-Header-swift_1E09NP8RKFO6-clang_1NNXX086AFKFR.pch' for bridging header '/Users/rodrigovasconcelos/MyApp/mobile/ios/MyApp-Bridging-Header.h'
```

The issue does not occurs if I try to build and archive using the latest stable version of XCode (9.4.1)
So far, I've tried to re-install my Pods, clean XCode derived data and `node_modules` folder, and also looked for similar issues, but nothing helped it.

Comment: Why do you want to archive the app using the beta version of Xcode?

Comment: @l'L'l I need to build a staging version using some features from iOS 12 before the launch in September.

Comment: Is the file in question (`RCTBridgeModule.h`) in the `React` directory? If so the error might be a case where Apple has made it more difficult to archive in the beta version of Xcode because of their policies. Another thing you might try is through `Application Loader` instead, that sometimes has been known to work alternatively.

Comment: @l'L'l The issue apparently was with how the new XCode handles custom configurations (That not Release or Debug). I'll post an answer with the fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was actually related to how React and Xcode handle custom project configurations (different then Release / Debug).
I stumbled upon the solution reading [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11813#issuecomment-273279257), but I'll paste it here in case the link somehow expires:

1. Added the React build target under the current scheme for my
   project. (Sidenote: if you're using fastlane to deploy, keep your
   project's build target in first place, otherwise fastlane gets
   confused and thinks you're building a library, so it never builds an
   ipa).
2. Added React under [Target] > Build Phases > Target Dependencies, which made Xcode build React before building the rest
   of the project.
3. Under [Target] > Build Settings, added a new User-Defined setting, called `REACT_HEADERS_PATH`. For all configurations not named
   Debug or Release, I set that to
   `$(BUILD_DIR)/Release-$(PLATFORM_NAME)/include`.
4. Under [Target] > Build Settings > Header Search Paths I added `$(REACT_HEADERS_PATH)` as an entry.

   Repeat for all targets in your project.